# Stopping a popup from opening twice

Tags: javascript, popup, popupwindow

Hi my problem is as follows: I have a popup window opening on pageload with a music player.
The problem is that the popup window opens every time i load the page. Also users are supposed to be able to choose if they want the music player to open the next time they visit the page. (Its on the homepage)

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
testpage music player
</title>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function popUp(URL) {
day = new Date();
id = day.getTime();
eval("page" + id + " = window.open(URL, '" + id + "', 'toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=0,width=200,height=250,top=690,left=390');");
}
</script>
</head>
<BODY onLoad="javascript:popUp('http://www.ccc-clan.com/board/popupex.html')">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

give your window a name

before the open, check for existence of the element with name...

http://tech.chitgoks.com/2009/09/11/javascript-check-if-popup-window-exists-using-its-window-name/

Answer (score 1):

eval = BAD

```
window["page" + id] = window.open(...)
```

Problem is these variables get destroyed and it is useless. Only way would be to set a session cookie that the window is open. When the pop up is closed, destroy the cookie.

But why music? So 1990's